# Basic question on almost sure convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I come across the following question:

Let $A_n$ be an $n\times n$ random matrix such that as $n\to\infty$ 
$$
\text{trace}(A_n)\to\text{trace}(\bar{A})\ \ \text{almost surely}
$$
Consider another $n\times n$ random matrix $B_n$. Is it true to claim that (as $n\to\infty$) ?
$$
\text{trace}(B_nA_n)-\text{trace}(B_n\bar{A})\to 0\ \ \text{almost surely}
$$

Question #2 : If it is known that for any deterministic matrix $C_n$ the following holds
$$
\text{trace}(C_nA_n)-\text{trace}(C_n\bar{A})\to0\ \ \text{almost surely}
$$
Is it true to claim that 
$$
\text{trace}(B_nA_n)-\text{trace}(B_n\bar{A})\to 0\ \ \text{almost surely}
$$
where $A_n$ and $B_n$ are the two random matrices defined in the previous question.

Comment: I believe you mean the second limit goes to $0$ almost surely?

Comment: Yes, thanks! I fixed it.

Comment: What would $\bar A$ mean? It seems to me the sequences $A_n$ and $B_n$ have matrices with growing dimensions as $n$ increases, so I am not sure how $B_n\bar A$ can be a valid expression.

Comment: You right. It should be $\bar{A}_n$ and $\bar{A}_n$ is a deterministic function.

Comment: I am still clueless about how you define $\bar A$ or $\bar A_n$ in your question.

Comment: Your "deterministic matrix" $C_n$ depends on $n$, so do you mean for any sequence of matrices that trace$(C_n A_n)$ tends to the desired limit?

Comment: D Poole - yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to both questions is "no". 
The trace of the product of two matrices is a sum-product of *all* elements of *both* matrices (it is equal to $\mathbf vec(A_n)\mathbf vec(B_n)$). In your question-proper you are making an assumption related only to the elements in the main diagonal of $A_n$. In a comment, you strengthened this assumption to convergence of all elements of the matrix $A_n$. Still, you make no assumptions related to the convergence of matrix $B_n$. Then the expression "$\text{trace}(B_nA_n)-\text{trace}(B_n\bar{A})\to 0\ \ \text{almost surely}$" does not follow. In practice $\text{trace}(B_nA_n)$ will tend to "look" like $\text{trace}(B_n\bar{A})$ as $n$ grows unbound, but this cannot be considered as a limit, since the latter expression may diverge , if $B_n$ diverges.

The premise of question #2# has nothing to do with the desired result, so it, too, does not follow.

Comment: Thanks. So, can you give an assumption regard the convergence of $B_n$ under which the claim is true. Regard the second question, I thought that if it is true to claim that for any deterministic matrix ($C_n$) the claim holds, and then I know something regard the "convergence of all elements of the matrix" $A_n$ (which is related to the beginning of your answer), then it will follows that "the randomness" of $B_n$ "is not critical". But, as I understand form you I most say something regard the convergence of $B_n$, right? BTW, you said "it will tend to look like", why?

Comment: Right, you must say something (a lot, actually) about the convergence of $B_n$. What must be said, is already in my answer. "Tend to look like": mathematically, as $n$ increases the elements of $A_n$ will converge to the elements of $\bar A$. So the expression $trace(B_n\bar A)$ is not "wrong" - but it is not a limit to which something else converges.